# how to encode and decode url in path string in java

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I have requirement such that i need to send a URL in Ajax and the URL is /somehost/users/{userid}/feed/{feedurl} where userid and feedurl are path params which will be
accepted in a servlet written Using Rest Frame work.

My Ajax call is

```
$.ajax({

        url : "/somehost/users/1/feeds/"+encodeURIComponent("**Please Think
                           that i passing a valid URL here**")),
        type : "DELETE",
            /*contentType: 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1',*/
        data : {feed_url : tr.attr("value")},  
....

....

....

)};
```

My servlet is

@Path("/users")

public class UserServlet  {

```
@DELETE
@Path("{user_id}/feeds/{feed_url}")

@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String deletefee(

    @PathParam("feed_url") String feedId,
    @PathParam("user_id") @DefaultValue("1") String userId) {
    System.out.println("I am in UserServlet delete");
}
```

}

1. Now i am not able hit my servlet.
2. I want to know how to send url as a @pathparam to my servlet.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the extra slash to "/somehost/users/1/feeds" so it becomes "/somehost/users/1/feeds/" does that work?

Currently you are accessing a URI like "/somehost/users/1/feeds1" instead of "/somehost/users/1/feeds/1"

Comment: hi immibis i have changed  "/somehost/users/1/feeds1" to "/somehost/users/1/feeds/1" still not working

Comment: Please some one answer my question quickly.